# domAttr.set(item, 'onclick', 'function(myObject)') doesn't work

Tags: dojo

I would like to set the `onClick` event to my item with a function taking an object in arg.

Like that:

```
item = domConstruct.create('li'); 
domAttr.set(item, 'innerHTML', structure.label);
domAttr.set(item, 'onClick', 'this.myFunction('+structure+')');
```

Problem is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
this.myFunction([object Object])
```

I know it works with this instruction :

```
item = domConstruct.create('li');
domAttr.set(item, 'innerHTML', structure.label);
domAttr.set(item, 'onClick', this.myFunction(structure));
```

But this way executes `myFunction` without clicking on the item.

I just want to click on the item (`li`) and then execute the code in `myFunction()`, but the function requires an argument.

EDIT :

Thanks a lot for your answer but I already tried this way.
It doesn't work too.

No error but my elem 'li' has no onClick attribute.
In the HTML console, what I see is : < li>Lien1< /li>

with this code :

```
domAttr.set(item, 'onClick', function(){ 
    this.myFunction(structure);
});
```

So when I click on my label 'Lien1', nothing happens. Probably because there is no onClick attribute. =/

It's the same problem with on and lang

I think it's just a little thing to change to make it work...

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Does the myFunction have to bee associated with 'this' or can it be its own function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I pass parameter from a dynamic created dijit button onClick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092434/can-i-pass-parameter-from-a-dynamic-created-dijit-button-onclick)

Comment: Yeah myFunction have to be associated with this. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Frode : No it is not a duplicate, I already tried to do this but it doesn't work ! Actually, it works with attribute onclick: function(){} for a button or a widget... Something like that but I'm trying to set an onclick attribute in li tag (it's a node).

Comment: @Renaud , it shouldn't be a problem to set onclick on li tags: http://jsfiddle.net/kbwhnuta/ Are you able to reproduce your problem in that fiddle?

Comment: @Frode It's complicated to reproduce my problem with the fiddle because actually, this little part of my code is in a big function taking a complex object (representing a whole structure of a 'list menu') it is a function which is capable to build all menu with a similar structure (menubar, floating menu, list menu,...)  Mh... I'm gonna try to add an 'a' elem to my menu into li tag and after that linked the onclick event to the 'a' tag. (I hope being understandable, I come from Belgium and I'm not really sure to be good in english) Thank you again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

you have to use dojo on then it will work

`item = domConstruct.create('li');
on(item,'click',lang.hitch(this,function(){ 
    this.myFunction(structure);
}));`

you have to use on and lang and then it will attach the listener on the click event

see more details at this link [link](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on)

another approach is like this

`item = domConstruct.create('li');
childitem = domConstruct.create('a',null,item);`

now you have both options either you do this
`on(childitem,'click',lang.hitch(this,function(){ 
    this.myFunction(structure);
}));`

or this

`domAttr.set(childitem, 'onClick', 'this.myFunction('+structure+')');`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. The same problem with domAttr.set(item,'onclick', function(){ 
    this.myFunction(structure);
});   --> my li tag in the console : <li>link1</li> missing the onclick attribute :/

Comment: ok then you can follow the standard practice by appending anchortag to your list items, i'm editing my answer, please take a look at another approach section

Comment: I tried again with domAttr.set(item, 'onclick', 'this.myFunction('+structure+')');  (without the 'a' elem)  And now, in my console, I get this : <li onclick="this.myFunction([object Object])">Link1</li> It seems better but when I click on 'link1', the error is : SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
this.myFunction([object Object])

Comment: since you are concatening the string your structure object is giving [object object] because that is the tostring function return. you have to call like this domAttr.set(item,'click',lang.hitch(this,function(){ this.myFunction(structure); }));

Comment: if you can create jsfiddle than it will be lot easier to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are just setting `onClick` attribute in `li` tag.
Without sending argument it's okey to,

```
domAttr.set(item, 'onClick', "myFunction()");
```

But sending argument,

```
domAttr.set(item, 'onClick', function(){myFunction(structure)});
```

This is just defining function so it won't call.
But note that when clicking the `li` in this case `structure` should be global variable.

Comment: Remember to use all lowercase "onclick" when working with the DOM element attributes.